# Is it possible to accurately detect all the APIs used in a website and how?

Tags: html, web-development-server, web-testing

I am trying to find examples of scrapers successfully detecting APIs used on websites. One example I know is the web extension ["Built With"](https://builtwith.com/) , but it fails to detect APIs from time to time, especially browser APIs.

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you in advance

Comment: using "devtools" > "network" > filter by selecting "fetch/XHR" > "CTRL+R" > you will see some json files. > Headers > General  > Request URL > and debug the information to see from what website they come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Puppeteer to scrape all request made by the page to detect APIs used. I've used this function to scrape JSON data from API requests made by the site instead of scrapping the page content itself, though it can be used to scrape the list of APIs called as well. Hope it helps.

```
  async scrapePageNetwork(url: string, ...spiedRequests: string[]) {
    const result = [];
    
    try {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.setRequestInterception(true);

      page.on('request', request => {
        requestClient({
          uri: request.url(),
          resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        }).then((response: any) => {
          result.push({
            url: request.url(),
            headers: request.headers(),
            postData: request.postData(),
            response: {
              headers: response.headers,
              size: response.headers['content-length'],
              body: response.body
            }
          });

          request.continue();
        }).catch((error: any) => {
          console.error(error);
          request.abort();
        });
      });

      await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

      await browser.close();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Failed to parse requests", err)
    }
    
    return result.filter((req) => spiedRequests.includes(req.url))
  }
```

Please note that this works only with the requests made directly by the page, i.e. if API called connects to a different API on the backend you won't be able to see that.

Comment: Sorry not to sound like a complete noob (which I am), but how would I exactly scrape the list of APIs. Just a nudge in the right direction would be all I need :)

Comment: No problem, we all start from somewhere :) There really isn't a defined way to do this from what I've seen. This method would return all network requests made by the page, you can filter those out by content-type headers or URLs to make it easier. E.g. check if content-type is application/json and assume it's an API call.

Comment: I can't give you points (because I'm new) but I'll give you a warm thank you, this helps a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you need any help along the way.